# inserting a variable within another variable string that contains an if statement

Tags: php, html

I have a string as follows and store it in the variable:

```
$div = '<div class="posts"> . $row['author'] .'<?php if('.$perm.'>1):?><br>&emsp;&emsp;'.$role.'</br>&emsp;&emsp;<a href="EditPage.php">Edit</a><?php endif ?></div>
```

What I want is to use this variable in another page so I need to insert the if statement to regulate permission so the content only displays with those users with above 1. It comes up with no syntax errors but when I run it this happens

```
John1):?>
Moderator
Edit
```

so the `1):?>` is being displayed when it shouldn't.

Any reasons why? or how I could do this better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an try like this:

```
$div ='<div class="posts">'.$row['author'].''; ?> <?php if($perm>1) {'<br>&emsp;&emsp;'.$role.'</br>&emsp;&emsp;<a href="EditPage.php">Edit</a>';} ''
```

I think its badly formated with single quotes ' , please check and lets see if it is.

Comment: Not sure what the double quotes at the end are for. When i inserted this i got syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional operator like this. The div section is kept at both statements just to improve readability.

```php
$div = if('.$perm.'>1) ? ('<div class="posts"> . $row['author'] . <br>&emsp;&emsp;'.$role.'</br>&emsp;&emsp;<a href="EditPage.php">Edit</a><div>') : ('<div class="posts"> . $row['author'] .'<div>');
```

Or:

```php
$div = '<div class="posts"> . $row['author'] .';
$div += if('.$perm.'>1) ? '<br>&emsp;&emsp;'.$role.'</br>&emsp;&emsp;<a href="EditPage.php">Edit</a><div>' : '<div>';
```